# Disable Removable Storage classes doesn't work via GPO on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

Could you please help me with very strange situation:

Test environment: DC - Windows Server 2012R2, Workstation - Windows 7 Professional N SP1

Case: disable USB via Group Policy.

Normally, I go to Computer or User configuration -> Administrative templates -> System -> Removable storage access and set All Removable Storage classes and set this option to Enabled.

After gpupdate and rebooting Windows 7 client nothing happens, USB drive still available for usage. There is no any errors or warnings in event viewer, there is records saying that Group Policy was successfully applied.

Then I tried to edit Default Domain Controller Policy for DC and it worked! I was frustrated about that. After deep research I found registry key that are responsible for this policy:

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\RemovableStorageDevices

and Deny_All key. On both Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows 7 it set to 1. But it works on 2012 and doesn't work on Windows 7.

Could you please hint me why this happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. The issue was Portable Device Enumerator service were set to start up Manual on target computer but needs to be set to automatic. According to this KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947294